# C# Windows 10 Universal App Set Storyboard From and To values from code

Tags: c#, storyboard, windows-10-universal

I am defining a storyboard as a Grid Resource. I have named it. I can set the TargetName property in code, but I cannot figure out how to set the From and To values of the storyboard in code. These values need to be set at runtime. Here is what I have.

```css
<Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="btnClick_SB" >
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" From="10" To="400" Duration="0:0:1.0" EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" From="10" To="400" Duration="0:0:1.0" EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
                </Storyboard>

...

<Canvas x:Name="cnvBL" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="White">
                <Line x:Name="lineBL1" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5" />
                <Line x:Name="lineBL2" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5" />
            </Canvas>

and the code

lineBL1.X1 = 10;
lineBL1.Y1 = 10;
btnClick_SB.Stop();

btnClick_SB.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, "lineBL1");            
btnClick_SB.Begin();
```

As you can see, From and To are set in XAML. I want to instead set those values in code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The Storyboard does not have a From and To property. It is the DoubleAnimation that has a From and To property. So, in the XAML, I just named the DoubleAnimations and deleted the From and To property settings. Then in code, I could reference the DoubleAnimations and set their properties.